# Find values in string

Tags: python

How can I summarize all the elements in text streams with delimiter `','`?

```
"a=10, a=12, b=5, b=4, c=3"

"a=2, b=5, b=6, b=7,c=10"

"c=10"
```

ie.

```
a_total=10+12+2

b_total=5+4+5+6+7

c_total=3+10+10
```

Comment: What have you tried based on your own research, and what was wrong with your attempt(s)? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Please read about [ask] and how to provide a [mre]. Your question should be based on your actual code with a specific error or problem you have with it. This is not the place for asking for "free" code. Also, your question is simply not clear. Please clarify the structure of your input, give an example input and the output you expect to get. Together with the current output of your [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this ugly way :

```
a = 0
b = 0
c = 0
listVarsInStrings =[a,b,c]
strgs = []
strgs.append("a=10,a=12,b=5,b=4,c=3")
strgs.append("a=2,b=5,b=6,b=7,c=10")
strgs.append("c=10")

for string in strgs:
  dicts = string.split(",")
  for dic in dicts:
    vars = dic.split("=")
    globals()[vars[0]]+=int(vars[1])

print(a,b,c)
```